# Ember-CLI/Node - node_modules / bower_components and non-internet accessible servers

Tags: node.js, ember.js, deployment

I'm currently building an Ember CLI app and now need to start thinking about deployment. My production server has no outbound internet access, being an intranet server, and my CI has limited outbound internet access, because enterprise.

For our Rails apps, this is not a huge problem, because all our dependencies are saved to `vendor/cache`, which the servers install from when installing in deployment mode. I haven't seen a similar instrument in the npm or bower documentation. I see various hosts (heroku, cloud foundry) have "build pack" extensions for this purpose, but I haven't seen anything for general purpose use.

I see that bower_components / node_modules are .gitignored by default, would it simply be a matter of adding these to source control?

Comment: what was your final solution?

Answer (score 0):

when you build a Ember-CLI application for production, it will automatically squash your vender files into a vender.js. So just copy the contents of your dist directory into the appropriate location on your webserver. you shouldn't be running ember server on production.

Comment: So is it typical to "Build for production" and then run a deploy script to move the /dist to the appropriate location? As opposed to deploying to the server and having the serve build itself?

Comment: "having the server build itself" as in running ember build production in a script on your server after a pull from git for example ? the issue with having bower modules and node modules in your version controll, is that you have a bulkier source code, and for eg wont get good metrics on code climate.

Comment: Yes, @Billybonks' solution is the recommended approach.